# Selecting data between two times (with other conditions too)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've been trying to select specific data from my database for about an hour now with no joy, would really appreciate any thoughts.

---

My MySQL database includes the following columns:

```
valid_time_start - time
valid_time_end - time

valid_expiry - date

valid_mon - tinyint(4)
valid_tue - tinyint(4)
valid_wed - tinyint(4)
valid_thu - tinyint(4)
valid_fri - tinyint(4)
valid_sat - tinyint(4)
valid_sun - tinyint(4)
```

I'm wanting to compare the current time/day with the list above in order to only select data that is available now.

i.e. if the current time is 12:04 on a Tues, 2nd April, I want it to select a record with the following cells:

```
valid_time_start: 11:00
valid_time_end: 13:00

valid_expiry: 10th Apr

valid_mon: 0
valid_tue = 1
valid_wed = 0 etc.
```

...but not if say, the valid_time_start was 12:30

I've been experimenting with `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date BETWEEN date1 AND date2"`, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the other parts. Perhaps is it best to just select everything in the mysql query and then use PHP to filter?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
WHERE valid_expiry > CURDATE()
  AND valid_time_start >= CURTIME()
  AND valid_time_end < CURTIME()
  AND CASE DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
        WHEN 1 THEN valid_mon
        WHEN 2 THEN valid_mon
        WHEN 3 THEN valid_tue
        WHEN 4 THEN valid_wed
        WHEN 5 THEN valid_thu
        WHEN 6 THEN valid_fri
        WHEN 7 THEN valid_sat
      END = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @andriy-m, I'm based in New Zealand (UTC+12:00), is there a way to include date_default_timezone_set('pacific/auckland') or something like that in the query?

Comment: @Jamie: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand you right. `CURTIME()` returns the time expressed in the current time zone, according to the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime). Do you mean `valid_time_start` and `valid_time_end` reflect a different time zone and you need some way of converting the times?